# I got error with subquery for translation table

Tags: postgresql, subquery

Using Postgressql 10 I had a function for grouped data calculation of votes summary and grouping by artist_name(table.field artist.name)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rt_reports_artists_votes_ratings(p_artist_list integer[], p_created_at_from timestamp without time zone, p_created_at_till timestamp without time zone, p_sort_type character varying DEFAULT 'by_sum_asc'::character varying, p_limit integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(created_at date, artist_name character varying, artist_id integer, vote_sum bigint, vote_qty bigint)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

SELECT cast( av.created_at as date) AS created_at, a.name as artist_name,
   av.artist_id,
   sum( av.vote ) AS vote_sum,
   count( av.id ) AS vote_qty
  from rt_artist_votes as av join
      rt_artists as a on a.id = av.artist_id
  WHERE ( CASE when p_artist_list IS NOT NULL THEN av.artist_id = ANY (p_artist_list) else true END ) AND

       ( av.created_at BETWEEN coalesce(p_created_at_from,rt_f_min_timestamp()) AND coalesce(p_created_at_till,rt_f_max_timestamp()) )


  group by cast( av.created_at as date), av.artist_id, artist_name
  ORDER by cast( av.created_at as date) asc,
     CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_asc' THEN
      sum( av.vote )
        end ASC,
     CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_desc' THEN
      sum( av.vote )
        end DESC,
     CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_artist_name' THEN
      a.name
  end ASC

  LIMIT p_limit ;

$function$
```

it worked ok, but I remade db structure for multilanguage support, so I added table :

```
CREATE TABLE public.rt_artist_translations (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    artist_id int4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    info text NOT NULL,
    locale varchar(2) NOT NULL,
```

and I try to remade this function where I try to get artist_name from subquery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rt_reports_artists_votes_ratings(p_artist_list integer[], p_created_at_from timestamp without time zone, p_created_at_till timestamp without time zone, p_sort_type character varying DEFAULT 'by_sum_asc'::character varying, p_limit integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(created_at date, artist_name character varying, artist_id integer, vote_sum bigint, vote_qty bigint)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

SELECT cast( av.created_at as date) AS created_at, ( SELECT a_t.name FROM rt_artist_translations AS a_t WHERE a_t.artist_id = av.artist_id AND a_t.locale= 'en' ) as artist_name,

   av.artist_id,

   sum( av.vote ) AS vote_sum,

   count( av.id ) AS vote_qty

  from rt_artist_votes as av join


      rt_artists as a on a.id = av.artist_id

  WHERE ( CASE when p_artist_list IS NOT NULL THEN av.artist_id = ANY (p_artist_list) else true END ) AND

       ( av.created_at BETWEEN coalesce(p_created_at_from,rt_f_min_timestamp()) AND coalesce(p_created_at_till,rt_f_max_timestamp()) )


  group by cast( av.created_at as date), av.artist_id, artist_name

  ORDER by cast( av.created_at as date) asc,

        CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_asc' THEN

            sum( av.vote )

        end ASC,

        CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_desc' THEN

            sum( av.vote )

        end DESC,

        CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_artist_name' THEN

            artist_name

        end ASC

  LIMIT p_limit ;

$function$
```

But I got error :

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "artist_name" does not exist
```

As I use artist_name in order/case in the end of the function.

How can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: I see about 100 lines of code, and this is not a minimal question.  Can you at least point out where you suspect the problem to lie?

Comment: At the bottom I show error : But I got error :

SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "artist_name" does not exist
As I use artist_name in order/case in the end of the function.

How can it be fixed?   Is it enogth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in SQL, you cannot reference a column alias such as *artist_name* in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. You need to reference the underlying named source which in this case is the subquery. Recall `SELECT` ironically being the first listed clause is usually the last step (or next to last) in the order of operations among most database engines.

However, it will be more efficient to move the subquery into a derived table (or CTE) to calculate column once and not separately for every row! With this approach, you then can reference the column name in all clauses of outer query. Consider the following adjustment:

```
 SELECT CAST( av.created_at as date) AS created_at,
        tr.artist_name,    
        av.artist_id,    
        SUM( av.vote ) AS vote_sum,    
        COUNT( av.id ) AS vote_qty

 FROM rt_artist_votes AS av 
 JOIN rt_artists AS a on a.id = av.artist_id
 JOIN 
     -- DERIVED TABLE
     (SELECT a_t.artist_id, a_t.name as artist_name
      FROM rt_artist_translations AS a_t 
      WHERE a_t.locale = 'en'
     ) AS tr
   ON tr.artist_id = av.artist_id

 WHERE (CASE 
            WHEN p_artist_list IS NOT NULL 
            THEN av.artist_id = ANY (p_artist_list) 
            ELSE true 
        END) 
   AND
       ( av.created_at BETWEEN coalesce(p_created_at_from, rt_f_min_timestamp()) 
                           AND coalesce(p_created_at_till, rt_f_max_timestamp()) 
       )    

 GROUP BY CAST( av.created_at as date), 
          av.artist_id, 
          tr.artist_name

 ORDER by CAST(av.created_at as date) ASC,
          CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_asc' 
               THEN SUM( av.vote )
          END ASC,
          CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_desc' 
               THEN SUM( av.vote )
          END DESC,
          CASE WHEN p_sort_type = 'by_sum_artist_name' 
               THEN tr.artist_name
          END ASC
```

You can even simply directly join on the translations table but here *tr.name* must be referenced in all clauses not its alias, *artist_name*.

```
 ...
 SELECT ... tr.name AS artist_name ...
 FROM rt_artist_votes AS av 
 JOIN rt_artists AS a on a.id = av.artist_id
 JOIN rt_artist_translations AS tr ON tr.artist_id = av.artist_id AND tr.locale = 'en'
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY ... tr.name ...
```